# Dajaxice not being parsed by template renderer?

Tags: django, dajaxice

Well i recently put my site into production and this is the last of a few bugs i need to fix. Basically `dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js` in returning this error in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %`. I have placed that particular folder into static and run collect static. The file is fetched however upon opening up the file from the error the django code embedded within the file is not being rendered.

I have placed the file wihtin the head of my base file. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is occuring. In my local envionment (development) it is working flawlessly. The only difference i had when installing the two is that i used pip to install it on production and on local i directly downloaded the file and installed it from github. How do i find the version of Dajaxice that is installed?

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is occuring?

Thanks